# ORA-01537. i want to search where the file is included

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> alter tablespace java add datafile 'd:/programming/java.dbf';
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01537: cannot add file 'd:/programming/java.dbf' - file already part of database


SQL> select TABLESPACE_NAME,FILE_NAME,STATUS from dba_data_files
2  where FILE_NAME='%JAVA.DBF';
no rows selected.
```

i just want to know the statement searching where the file is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `like` instead of `=`:

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_NAME,STATUS 
from dba_data_files
where UPPER(FILE_NAME) like '%JAVA.DBF';
```

Comment: I think the filename is case-sensitive as well.

Comment: i did copy the statement and paste. but.....
`SQL> select TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_NAME,STATUS
  2  from dba_data_files
  3  where FILE_NAME like '%JAVA.DBF';
no rows selected.`
what statement do i must enter?TTTTTTT

Comment: As Jeffry said, the file name is case sensitive. Change JAVA.DBF to lower case